# Size of multi dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I was trying to get the size of a multidimensional array and wrote code in C as shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char b[3][4];

int main(void){
    printf("Size of array b[3]=%d\n", sizeof(b[3]));  
    printf("Size of array b[2]=%d\n", sizeof(b[2]));
    printf("Size of array b[5]=%d\n", sizeof(b[5]));

    return 0;
}
```

In all above three print statements, I am getting size equal to 4. Can someone explain how `sizeof` works in case of a multi-dimensional array? Why is the output the same in the third print?

Comment: `sizeof()` gives `size_t`, you need `%zu` as format specifier.

Comment: may this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274162/how-to-find-2d-array-size-in-c

Comment: @RadRunner good point. I will make sure to use %zu when I use C99 and later version. Otherwise, I may have to use just %u.

Comment: @MCG: Whatever you use, don' tforget to convert the value to the appropriate type. If you want to use `%u`, then it should be `printf("... %u...", (unsigned) sizeof(b[5]));`.

Comment: @RoadRunner: From the very nitpickishly pedantic point of view, in this case the OP is using `sizeof`, not `sizeof()`. The `()` is a part of argument expression (a redundant part, BTW) not of operator itself :)

Comment: @AnT Yes, you are correct. Using  `sizeof b[3]` would be acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`b` is a 2D character array of rows `3` and columns `4`.

So, if you take `sizeof(b)` you will get `12`.

`b[0]` (and `b[i]` in general) has a type of a 1D character array of size `4`. So. if you take `sizeof (b[0])` you will get `4`.

`b[0][0]` (and `b[i][j]` in general) has a type of `char`. So if you take `sizeof (b[0][0])` you will get `1`.

`sizeof` does not depend on the array index. The type remains the same even for `b[0]` and `b[100]`, even though it might be out of range of the memory of the array.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje `sizeof()` won't check for constraint. like iin `b[100]` answer is `4` only.

Comment: @MCG: `sizeof b[5]` is perfectly fine in non-evaluated context (since `b[i]` is not a VLA).

Comment: It is not correct to claim that "C will happily allow to assign data to `b[100]`". This would trigger *undefined behavior*. Undefined behavior is allowed to manifest itself in many different ways, including at compile time as compiler refusing to translate the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator operates on the type only.

The type of `b` is an array of three elements which are arrays of four chars: `char[3][4]`.

Now the array subscript operator `b[n]` is defined to be equivalent to `*(b + n)`, and when an array is used in the context of pointer arithmetic (the expression `b + n`), it decays into a pointer to its first element. So, the expression `b + n` has the type `char (*)[4]`, and dereferencing that yields again an array with the type `char[4]`.
*TL;DR*: The type of `b[n]` is `char[4]`, irrespective of the value of `n`.

And that type is what the `sizeof` operates on: `sizeof(b[n])` is perfectly equivalent to `sizeof(char[4])`, and it is guaranteed to always yield `4`.